# Showing a list of top-selling products in a given collection but omitting a specific one?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm looking to create a section of a product page where I show the top selling products in a certain collection, but omitting the one whose product page this is displayed on.

As of right now, I do not see any option to sort the collections object aside from the way it is sorted by default. Likewise, I do not see a way to omit a given `product.id` from the returned results.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
{% for top_product in collections['somecollection'].products limit:4 %}
<div class="top-seller-item">
  <img src="{{ top_product.images[0] | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"/>
  <a href="{{ top_product.url }}">{{ top_product.title }}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This just returns the first four products of the collection `somecollection`.

I can't imagine this is an uncommon use case, so does anyone know a way to do something like `SORTBY sales OMIT product.id` (pseudocode, of course, but that's the idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the sorting order of the collection to be by "Best Selling".

After that you will need to create a counter variable that will count the unique products in your loop.

In addition you have to change the limit to 5 so that you get 4 elements even if the product is present in the first 4 products.

In code it will look something like this:

```
{%- assign counter = 0 -%}
{% for top_product in collections['somecollection'].products limit:5 %}
    {%- unless top_product.id == product.id or counter >= 4 -%}
    {%- assign counter = counter | plus: 1 -%}
        <div class="top-seller-item">
            <img src="{{ top_product.images[0] | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"/>
            <a href="{{ top_product.url }}">{{ top_product.title }}</a>
        </div>
    {%- endunless -%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! Two quick fixes - your code always outputs five items. The comparison should be between id and id, since id and handle will always be different, and it should stop outputting at either of the two conditions, so I changed the `and` to an `or`.

Comment: @AKor yep, you are correct. Didn't check it for errors I was at work. :D I updated the code.